# Why is dictionary not printing updated value Python 3.6

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.6

Each time 'g' is entered into the input field, the dictionary 'goal-totals' should be updated and the new value reflected in the printed 'totals' output. The code works all but for the first time an entry 'g' is entered. How do I make the first entry reflect in the printed 'totals' output?

```
from IPython.display import clear_output
     
goal_totals = {'goals' :0}              
active = True
while active:
  totals = f'Goals: {goal_totals["goals"]}'
  
  command = input()
  if command == 'g':
    goal_totals["goals"] += 1
    clear_output()
    print(totals)
```

Comment: You should be posting minimal reproducible example, check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I did not downvote, instead I tried to help you :) so you don't end up getting only downvotes :)

Comment: Check the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it should help.

The code calculates the totals each time after its updated.

```py
from IPython.display import clear_output
     
goal_totals = {'goals' :0}              
active = True
while active:
    command = input()
    if command == 'g':
        goal_totals["goals"] += 1
    totals = f'Goals: {goal_totals["goals"]}'
    clear_output()
    print(totals)
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample code on what you are planning to acheive with an expected output :) May be I can help

Comment: Not sure how to do that without writing too much.:) There will be 22 if statements (one for each type of event) that will update the dictionary. The totals f-string will include all 22 event types as placeholders. I'm just showing the goals here to not be repetitive. Ideally, the (long) totals f-string will live above the first 'if statements' to save having to include it in each of the 22 if statements.

Comment: May be you could use it then at the end of the all ```if statements```, so that every ```if statement``` calculates the required metric and then the ```total``` at the end would print it all. Check I updated the code accordingly.

Comment: It works! Thank you. I really appreciate your time. I'm slowly learning. I know comments are not meant to be for saying thank you so I'll delete it half an hour. Shall we also tidy up by deleting our earlier comments?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242656/discussion-between-gospel77-and-alonso).